# How to change main page as Identity's Login page(with different template) in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm trying to create the initial page that comes up as soon as the program runs in an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project. I want this initial page to be the login screen from Identity. I will customize this login screen using an external template I found. In the template I've applied, I want the login button to redirect to different pages based on the role of the person logging in. There are two roles in the project, and I want each of them to be directed to their respective pages when they log in. How can I achieve this?

Here is my program.cs:

```
global using Infrastructure.Identity;
global using Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            var connectionStringIdentity = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TalentFlowIdentityDb") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'TalentFlowIdentityDb' not found.");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringIdentity));
            var connectionStringMain = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TalentFlowDb") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'TalentFlowDb' not found.");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<TalentFlowDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringMain));
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {                
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            });

            builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", ""));


            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

            //app.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=LoginPage}/{id?}");


            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var appIdentityDb = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                await ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(appIdentityDb, roleManager, userManager);
            }


            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `Login.cshtml.cs` in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        if (roles.Contains("Role1"))
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Path/To/Role1Page");
        }
        else if (roles.Contains("Role2"))
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Path/To/Role2Page");
        }
        else
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply onupicakci. However your code did not solve my problem but of course it showed me a way how to do it. I changed the `OnPost` method as in the code below and now I don't have any issues anymore:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
       returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

       ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            IList<string> roles = new List<string>();
            //var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var _userid = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
            if (_userid != null)
            {
                var id = _userid.Id;
                await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(_userid);
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(_userid);
                roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_userid);
            }
            //var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).Result;

            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            if (roles[0] == "CompanyManager")
            {
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);

            }
            else if (roles[0] == ("Personnel"))
            {
                var localUrl = Url.Action("Index", "PersonnelMainPage", new { area = "Personnel" });
                return LocalRedirect(localUrl);

            }




        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```